# ReactJS When I use any handleClick, other handleClicks fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to build a guess a number game. 
I have written a button to guess a number, a button to generate a random number, and a button to compare the guessed number vs the generated number.
When I click the guess number button, the handleClickCompare method fires and I get the console.log inside it.and everytime handleChange is fired handleClickCompare also fires . and sometimes but not everytime when I press the guess button a new random number is generated. 
what is going on?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ guess:0, gen:0 }
  }

  handleChange(guess, e) {
    this.setState({guess: e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  // handleChange(guess, event) {
  //   this.setState([guess]: event.target.value);
  //   console.log(this.state);
  // }
  handleClick(guess, e) {
    this.setState({ guess: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  handleClickGen(gen,e){
    this.setState({gen: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)});
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  handleClickCompare(guess, gen) {
    if (gen<guess) {
    console.log("guess lower");
    }
    if (guess < gen) {
      console.log("guess higher");
    }else {
      console.log("You got it chief");
    }
  }
  


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
        Enter a number
        </p>
        <input
          value={this.state.guess}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "guess")}
          type="number"
        />
        {/* <input name={guess} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)} /> */}
        {/* <input type="text" name="guess" value={this.state.title}
                     onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/> */}
        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "guess")}>
          guess{" "}
        </button>

        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClickGen.bind(this, "gen")}>
          gen a number{" "}
        </button>

        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClickCompare(this.state.guess, this.state.gen)}>
          compare{" "}
        </button>



      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

>

Comment: Ali, Please let us know if the solution below works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems and a few bad practices in your code. Let's start with your callback function.

```
this.handleChange.bind(this, "guess")
```

You don't need to bind your functions like this. It is unnecessary since even if you use it by reference you can get the `event` argument. Also, you can bind your functions in the class constructor to use `this`. If you bind your functions like that they are recreated in every render.

```
this.handleClickCompare(this.state.guess, this.state.gen)
```

For this one, there are two problems. First one is, you don't need to give arguments to this function. You can get those arguments from your state in your function definition. It is not necessary. The second problem is you are invoking this function immediately instead of using it with a callback. You can use it with an arrow function:

```
() => this.handleClickCompare()
```

But again, this is unnecessary. You can use it by reference and get the arguments from the state.

Another problem is in your `handleChange` function.

```
handleChange(guess, e) {
    this.setState({guess: e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

From your input, you are getting a string and set it to the state than compare with a number. So, use `Number()` to set a number.

```
this.setState({ guess: Number(e.target.value) });
```

Your `handleClickGen` function actually generates every time a number but you think sometimes it is not.

```
this.setState({gen: Math.floor(Math.random()*10)});
```

This because you see `0` sometimes right? Reason for this is your function generates numbers between 0-9. So when your number is something like `0,...`, your function floors it to 0. So, change it like that.

```
this.setState({ gen: Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 });
```

Your `handleClickCompare` logic is a little bit wrong, change it like that:

```
handleClickCompare() {
  const { guess, gen }  = this.state;
  console.log( guess, gen );
  if (guess < gen) {
    console.log("guess lower");
  } else if (guess > gen) {
    console.log("guess higher");
  } else {
    console.log("You got it chief");
  }
}
```

Lastly, do not log your state after updating it immediately in a function. `setState` is asynchronous. You can log it in your render method like I did below.

By the way, I've changed the "guess" option with "reset" since your `handleChange` function already set `guess` state.

So, here is the whole code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { guess: 0, gen: 0 };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClickGen = this.handleClickGen.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClickCompare = this.handleClickCompare.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ guess: Number(e.target.value) });
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ guess: 0 });
  }

  handleClickGen() {
    this.setState({ gen: Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 });
  }

  handleClickCompare() {
    const { guess, gen }  = this.state;
    console.log( guess, gen );
    if (guess < gen) {
      console.log("guess lower");
    } else if (guess > gen) {
      console.log("guess higher");
    } else {
      console.log("You got it chief");
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p className="App-intro">
          Enter a number
        </p>
        <input
          value={this.state.guess}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="number"
        />
        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Reset{" "}
        </button>

        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClickGen}>
          gen a number{" "}
        </button>

        <button type="button"
          onClick={this.handleClickCompare}>
          compare{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you write youe onClick handlers makes then run everytime the component is rendered, and not only onClick.

You should write, for example, as follows:

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick.bind(this, "guess")}>
```

Updated following your correct comments: bind is missing in the last handler.

Comment: you can use bind as well. That is correct syntax. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: The problem is not bind, but the fact that you pass a parameter. Without a parameter onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} is fine, with the parameter you need the syntax provided in my reply.

Comment: The syntax is correct for passing parameters. Please check the official documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Comment: Oops, right. Learning something new every day :) but you haven't used bind in the last function...

Comment: @Yossi is not talking about binding here I think. OP invokes the function immediately, this why it runs in the first render but not with the click. So, Yossi's suggestion solves this problem. But again, this function is also recreated in every render (not run, recreated).

Comment: Ah, sorry @Yossi is talking about `handleClick` function here. I meant `handleClickCompare` function. OP invokes it immediately.

Comment: The button stopped working when I did what you said. Do i need to install babel for it to work?

Comment: If you don't have Babel you can't use JSX here. Do you mean any plugin? Just look at the code in my answer. It works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a bind here:

```
 <button type="button"
      onClick={this.handleClickCompare.bind(this.state.guess, this.state.gen)}>
      compare{" "}
    </button>
```

Please find the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/m4z2y9jmr8

Comment: He is not using **this.state** in `handleClickCompare`. So do he need to bind that function to ?

Comment: Whenever we pass any parameter, we need to use the arrow function or bind syntax. I have updated the answer with the code with bind added in handleClickCompare. Else the function will always run right.

Comment: but I run your code without bind with `handleClickCompare` and that goes perfect .

Comment: Does it? The function always runs right. You can see the console logs .

Comment: Actually, OP does not need any arguments directly as here. Also, binding functions in JSX props cause the function recreation in every render. The function reference is enough here.

Comment: That fixed the compare button! thanks! but the rest still is not working properly

Comment: @devserkan , I agree, I was just pointing out the syntax error in the code. All the others are logical errors , which I suppose the OP should be able to fix with the help of your points below.

Comment: Ali, Please look at the points below by devserkan to fix the logical errors in your code. Feel free to mark the below answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right here. Rest of the problems are mostly logical.